# Error when publishing MVC websystem in Windows Server 2008

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, server, web-deployment

When i publish my MVC 5 websystem ,below error appear when i check in Google Chrome inspect element.

[image]

Below are the code i add in my View:

```
@model abc.def.Models.ClsSECEditors

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<style type="text/css">
    .deleteLink {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<link href="/Content/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/jqsimplemenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<!-- Script for menu -->
<script src="/Scripts/jqsimplemenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/Functions/SECEditor.js"></script>
<br>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "abc" }))
{...}
```

When i develop using my laptop, there is no issues and works find. I'm not sure why when i publish it, all the errors appear. Can you guys help me to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with last script you loaded. Anyway just try to use `Url.Content()` method to resolve path.

Do it like :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Functions/SECEditor.js")></script>
```

And do this for all css and js reference on page you have described in sample code.

You can find basic info on below link:

[Url.Content() to resolve relative urls from cshtml](http://webactivedirectory.com/asp-net/asp-net-use-url-content-from-razor-to-resolve-relative-urls/)

Let me know if doesn't work.

Comment: hi @simple man..i'm not sure where do i need to change my code. Can you please help?

Comment: can i know how to add this in the css reference? right now i just try it for js reference but still error :(

Comment: You can do same for css. Pass the path of file. What error you are getting? Have you checked the path of file? Or have you deployed your site in virtual directory?

Comment: I have seen your image and there is 404 not found for bootstrap.css. File path is correct for bottstrap.css? Is it inside Content folder or inside another one?